# Extra line when using Plot and Show together

Tags: plotting

I have shown some plots by using `Show` and `Plot` together. The problem is that an extra blue line is created in the output which I can not remove it. This is my code:

```
v = 2;
tr = -2;
ro = 2;    
both = Plot[{v x/(-4 tr)}, {x, -20, 0}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, Filling -> ro tr - 1, FillingStyle -> {Directive[Opacity[0.55], Blue]}, GridLines -> {None, {0.5}}];
bothh = Plot[{v x/(-4 tr)}, {x, -20, -16}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, Filling -> ro tr, FillingStyle -> {Directive[Opacity[0.55], Blue]},GridLines -> {None, {0.5}}];
Show[both, bothh, PlotRange -> All, Axes -> True,LabelStyle -> Directive[Large, Black]]
```

Could anyone help me?

*By extra line I mean the line which is created between two regions

Comment: Use `PlotStyle -> None` in `both` and `bothh`?

Comment: It creates white points :( @kglr

Comment: or try  `Show[both, bothh, PlotRange -> All, Axes -> True, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Large, Black]] /. Line[x_] :> Sequence[]`

Comment: It still creates white points @kglr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Plot[Max[ ro tr, v x/(-4 tr)], {x, -20, 0}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
 Filling -> ro tr - 1, FillingStyle -> Opacity[0.55, Blue], 
 GridLines -> {None, {0.5}}, PlotRange -> All, Axes -> True, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Large, Black], Exclusions -> None]
```

[image]

Comment: There is still a white line.

Comment: @Albert, could you try the updated version with `Exclusions->None`?

Comment: It works perfectly. Great answer! Thank you